# Why can't I loop through 2 Doubly Linked Lists using while?

Tags: java, while-loop, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Ok, so the task is:

Given 2 Integer Lists, merge them into one by following these rules:

1. Add all the even numbers from both lists interchangebly (list1 starting from the first, list2 starting from the last)
2. Add all the remaining even numbers from the list1.
3. Add all the remaining even numbers from list2.
4. Add all the odd numbers from list1 starting from the first
5. Add all the odd numbers from list2 starting from the last.

So for ex.

list1: 1 2 3 4 4 5 6
list2: 7 8 9 10

list3 should be: 10 2 8 4 4 6 1 3 5 9 7

However my function returns 2 4 4 6 8 10 1 3 5 7 9

Here's the function I have writen:

```
public static void merge(DLL<Integer> list1 , DLL<Integer> list2, DLL<Integer> list3) {

    DLLNode<Integer> curr1=list1.getFirst();
    DLLNode<Integer> curr2=list2.getLast();

    while (curr1!=null && curr2!=null) {

        if (curr1.element%2==0) list3.insertLast(curr1.element);
        curr1=curr1.succ;

        if (curr2.element%2==0) list3.insertLast(curr2.element);
        curr2=curr2.pred;
    }

    if (curr1!=null) {
        while (curr1!=null) {
            if (curr1.element%2==0)
                list3.insertLast(curr1.element);
            curr1=curr1.succ;
        }
    }

    if (curr2!=null) {
        while (curr2!=null) {
            if (curr2.element%2==0)
                list3.insertLast(curr2.element);
            curr2=curr2.pred;
        }
    }

    curr1=list1.getFirst();
    while (curr1!=null) {
        if (curr1.element%2!=0)
            list3.insertLast(curr1.element);
        curr1=curr1.succ;
    }

    curr2=list2.getLast();
    while (curr2!=null) {
        if (curr2.element%2!=0)
            lista.insertLast(curr2.element);
        curr2=curr2.pred;
    }



}
```

Somehow, it doesn't enter the first while loop. What could be the cause of that?

Comment: did you try debugging it

Comment: If it doesn't enter the first `while`-loop, then maybe the `DLL` class methods `getFirst()` and `getLast()` are buggy?

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal I did, it didn't show anything.

Comment: @kiltek I checked them first, they are working the way they should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding the even elements **interchangeably**. If the first element of the output list should be an even element of the first list, you must iterate the first list until you find the first even element on that list. On then you should start iterating over the second list.

You can use a flag that will tell you from which list the next even element should be taken:

```
boolean takeFirst = true;
while (curr1!=null && curr2!=null) {
    if (takeFirst) { // next even element should come from the first list
        if (curr1.element%2==0) {
            list3.insertLast(curr1.element);
            takeFirst = false;
        }
        curr1=curr1.succ;
    }
    if (!takeFirst) { // next even element should come from the second list
        if (curr2.element%2==0) {
            list3.insertLast(curr2.element);
            takeFirst = true;
        }
        curr2=curr2.pred;
    }
}
```